# Three.js - always render skybox independent from camera clipping

Tags: three.js

I'm using `PerspectiveCamera` with clipping set to 0.1 - 2000. Skybox has a size of 4000, making it invisible as it's outside the far plane.

Is it possible to always render skybox (or any mesh) without increasing the far plane?